# Content width, tablet screen, flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My layout looks ok on different devices, but with the tablet, I have a problem. The horizontal scroll is appearing. I'm using flexbox, everywhere the width is 100%. On small devices, it's just should create rows.

Problem screenshot: [image]

Thank you!

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#flexrow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#navigation {
    width: 20%;
}

#content {
    width: 60%;
    text-align: justify;
}

#rellinks {
    width: 20%;
}

footer {
    
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #flexrow {
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #navigation, #rellinks {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #content {
        width: 100%;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

  }
```

Comment: It might help to include your HTML and make a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to set `box-sizing: border-box;` to your #wrapper or #flexrow.

Here's an explanation from Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This means that when you set width and height, you have to adjust the value you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added. For example, if you have four boxes with width: 25%;, if any has left or right padding or a left or right border, they will not by default fit on one line within the constraints of the parent container.

Comment: I don't see any border or padding in the OP's code.

Comment: @showdev box-sizing is just a guess based on what's available and my experience with similar issues

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced it and in my case `body` for *narrow* screens had a `margin` from user agent.
This fixed the issue:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Second option:

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```